# Do Java and Gradle have different source structure for modules?

Tags: java, gradle, java-module

I saw that in [Gradle](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#step_4_use_the_code_experimental_jigsaw_code_plugin_to_do_the_same_thing), we declare a module as `artifact/src/main/java/module-info.java`, but in [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#greetings) they declare it as `src/com.group.artifact/module-info.java`. Then in [Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) we have `src/main/java/com.group.artifact/module-info.java`.

I am confused, which one should I use? I have a Gradle project that contains multiple subprojects inside. And I am trying to use the subprojects as modules. IntelliJ IDEA gives an error when I use the Jenkov method, and I have to switch to Gradle one. Is it the same?

Answer (score 3):

OpenJDK and Gradle simply have different conventions for structuring source code. Since you're using Gradle (and therefore Gradle's Java language plugin), you should follow it's conventions. Gradle's Java language plugin will automatically compile the code in the directory `src/main/java`.

Assuming you have two modules, `com.example.moduleone` and `com.example.moduletwo`, your project's structure should look like this:

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
moduleone
├──src
│  └──main
│     └──java
│        ├──{PACKAGES_AND_CODE}
│        └──module-info.java
└──build.gradle
moduletwo
├──src
│  └──main
│     └──java
│        ├──{PACKAGES_AND_CODE}
│        └──module-info.java
└──build.gradle
```

*Not* using Gradle and compiling your project yourself with `javac -d out --module-source-path src -m com.example.moduleone,com.example.moduletwo`, it should look like this:

```
src
├──com.example.moduleone
│  ├──{PACKAGES_AND_CODE}
│  └──module-info.java
└──com.example.moduletwo
   ├──{PACKAGES_AND_CODE}
   └──module-info.java
```

As for the 'Jenkov method': I've never seen this structure before, it looks like a weird mix and I recommend not to use it. It would probably be just confusing for other developers.

Comment: I am revisiting this post, and I found that Gradle doesn't share the module directory name with the module name itself. In [Gradle's module docs](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#step_1_produce_a_java_9_module_for_a_single_subproject) , the directory name excludes group id.

Comment: @Arkyo I've updated the answer – the main point of it was never wrong though. I'm sure, the names of a submodule's directory are irrelevant to Gradle.  
I added two missing `build.gradle` files in the submodules directories as well, which where missing in the original post.